# Is there a faster way to convert data to a byte and then back into its original form?

Tags: java

I am using a queue service that only takes messages as byte so I need to convert my data quickly to the format and then make it back to its original when I receive work from the queue.  My data format is a INT, DOUBLE, and INT[] and here's how I did it at first

```
//to convert to string
String[] message = { Integer.toString(number), String.valueOf(double), Arrays.toString(my_list) };
message.asString;
//to convert back
String message_without_brackets = message.replace("[", "" ).replace("]", "");
String[] temp_message = message_without_brackets.split(","); 

int interger = Integer.valueOf(temp_message[0]);
double double = Double.valueOf(temp_message[1]);
int[] my_list = new int[temp_message.length-2]; //-2 because the first two entries are other data

for (int i = 2; i < temp_message.length; i++) {
    my_list[i-2] = Integer.parseInt(temp_message[i].replace(" ",""));
}
```

This is super ugly and it annoyed me that after a few weeks(or a single night of heavy drinking) I would probably not be able to figure out this quickly.  Performance wise the code wasn't too bad, I think `replace` was the heaviest part of the code(if I remember it was like 15% of overall execution).

I asked around and found [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to be able to do this cleaner but the performance is now over 40% of my loop now(its Gson itself thats doing it):

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    int[] sub = { 0, 59, 16 };
    Object[] values = { 0, 43.0, sub };
    String output = gson.toJson(values); // => [0, 43.0,[0,59,16]]

    Object[] deserialized = gson.fromJson(output, Object[].class);
    System.out.println(deserialized[0]);
    System.out.println(deserialized[1]);
    System.out.println(deserialized[2]);
```

So I'm wondering if there's faster way to get the same result?I am trying out a few of the suggestions in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library) but is there a faster way to do this without depending on any external libraries as my needs are quite simple(if not, then is there a fast one)?  Because someone suggested Gson, I looked at Json parsers, but is that what I should be looking for or is are there other types of libraries that do this?

EDIT: I am converting it to string because I thought I needed to do that to send it as `getBytes()`, is there any other format that would be faster that I can use `getBytes()` on?

Comment: You could maybe have a class that holds the int, double and int[], and serialize/deserialize it.

Comment: There are lots of faster ways to do this. What are you doing with the Strings? i.e. why are they needed because the fastest approach is to not use them at all.

Comment: @PeterLawrey the queue server(to my knowledge) requires data to sent as `getBytes()` I thought I needed to convert it to a string in order to do that..

Comment: @assylias I have a method within my class that does it, but I'm trying to figure out the fastest way.

Comment: If you want bytes, why not create a `byte[]` instead? Ideally, you could write directly to wherever the byte[] is written to (skipping the need for a byte[])

Comment: @PeterLawrey because I'm dumb :-( I just realized that I could convert it directly to bytes, in all the examples I saw people using strings so I thought that was the way to do it.  I edited my question but does the question still apply since I need something to convert the data into bytes and then back or is there now just a more simple way to do it since I don't need strings?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm still a bit confused..say I convert my int,double,int[] to a byte[] and then push to the queue..how do I convert it back without a json library? using my string method I was parsing it for commas and stuff..would that work with bytes[]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a DataOutputStream like

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);

int i = 0;
double d = 43.0;
int[] sub = { 0, 59, 16 };

dos.writeInt(i);
dos.writeDouble(d);
dos.write(sub.length);
for (int j : sub)
    dos.writeInt(j);

byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

If you want to get more extreme you can use recycled ByteBuffers or even direct ByteBuffers and use native byte ordering. etc.

Comment: Thanks so much Peter, but how do I convert it back(I can use this logic to send to the queue but when things come back I  need to convert them back to original format to process)?

Comment: Use a ByteArrayInputStream to wrap the byte[] and a DataInputStream to wrap that. Then use readInt/Double where I have used writeXxx().

Comment: got it, it worked for int and double, but how do I get the int[] back? I tried to do another readInt and got some numbers but it wasn't like I had in the list..Is there a way to get the list?

Comment: I figured it out! instead of using DataOutputStream I used ObjectOutputStream and did everything else the same except for the list, I wrote it as an object(didn't do the for loop). Seems to work, I'll test performance.  By the way I never thanked you Peter for suggesting Yourkit, I finally forked out the cash for it and its really good I'm learning a lot and thinking of my code in new ways. I can't thank you enough for that suggestion and all your help in my journey to learn java. Thanks!

Comment: ObjectOutputStream is a good choice if you have to pass Serializable. However, it relatively complex and inefficient. e.g it can use 10x as many bytes and take 10x longer or more.

Comment: I didn't know it had that kind of overhead(I haven't had a chance to profile my code yet). I like how with ObjectOutputStream, I can send an int, double and object(int[]) and I don't need to do any parsing to get it out I just read them back. Do you know if thats possible with DataInputStream?  I'm so confused, I am playing with the code and realize I can't use an interator and doesn't seem to be able to put this in a for loop..I think I need to just read the stream of int after the double but without an interator not sure how to go through the list.

Comment: I agree I wouldn't use an iterator. I would read the length of objects to read, create an array of that length and then loop through each element you need to read.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at Guava? I use it all the time for handling byte streams

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#toByteArray(java.io.InputStream)

the library is worth it just for toByteArray()